# Ssl error while uploading huge file on Android using Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: android, ssl, https, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I've got a problem.

I'm using Titanium SDK 5.1.1.GA and Play framework 2.3.* with Java 1.8.

The problem is when I'm uploading several files in one multipart POST request via bad network (3G for example) I'm receiving that error:

```
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: (TiHttpClient-9) [60597,61749] HTTP Error (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException): javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7b93c2a0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744 0x743667e8:0x00000000)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7b93c2a0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744 0x743667e8:0x00000000)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:469)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:1014)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:955)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:411)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:343)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:143)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldInt(URLConnection.java:544)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(URLConnection.java:316)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContentLength(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:182)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient.handleResponse(TiHTTPClient.java:158)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient.access$1200(TiHTTPClient.java:84)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$ClientRunnable.run(TiHTTPClient.java:1198)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7b93c2a0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744 0x743667e8:0x00000000)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:426)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    ... 15 more
```

I've tested it on Android 4.1, 4.4.2 with different devices and depending on device I receiving that error when uploading files with total size more than 5mb.
If I'm using good WiFi connection or trying to upload file with total size less then 5 mb then everything is fine.

Total files size depends on phone. The better the phone than possible file size is larger.

Moreover, if I connect from phone A to phone B via WiFi and phone B has 3g connection to internet, then I got that error too, but if I'm using proxy server that emulates bad connection than no error appears.

Comment: It looks like you might have found a bug or undocumented limitation. Stack Overflow is [not the right place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) to report bugs. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: Unfortunately it is very hard to reproduce the bug as it depends on internet connection and server side.
Detailed information about the bug can be found in the link above.
I'll add task to Jira when I solve the problem.